# Optimal Method to Log Data using DJI UXSDKDemo (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dji-sdk

I would like to pull the values from the two classes below and log them in a file. What is the best method to pull these values? Would a property observer work and be effective? Is there a main loop or clock that I can use to consistently call and log this data? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    //IMU
EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUState;
EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUsCount;

EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUStateGyroscopeState;
EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUAccelerometerState;
EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUStateCalibrationProgress;
EXTERN_KEY NSString *const DJIFlightControllerParamIMUStateCalibrationState;
```

Is this relevant?

```
 @class DJIFlightHubManager;


/**
 *  Delegate to receive updated states related to DJI FlightHub.
 */
@protocol DJIFlightHubManagerDelegate <NSObject>


/**
 *  Updates states for the uploading progress of flight data.
 *  
 *  @param flightHubManager The FlightHub Manager updates the state.
 *  @param state The updated state. When it is `DJIFlightHubUploadStateRejectedByServer`, refer to error for more detail.
 *  @param error The returned error when the upload request is rejected by the server. Use the error to check the reason.
 */
- (void)flightHubManager:(DJIFlightHubManager *)flightHubManager didUpdateUploadState:(DJIFlightHubUploadState)state error:(nullable NSError *)error;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DJIFlighthubManager will not be relevant in this case - it corresponds to our [FlightHub device](https://www.dji.com/flighthub)

For each of the keys you want to write to a file you will need to get and listen to the state first, then write the data to a file.  Here is an example:

```
DJIFlightControllerKey *exampleKey = [DJIFlightControllerKey keyWithParam:DJIFlightControllerParamIMUState];

// Will get called once to get current value of the key
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] getValueForKey:exampleKey withCompletion:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable value, NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];

// Called only when the value for the key changes
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] startListeningForChangesOnKey:exampleKey withListener:self andUpdateBlock:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable oldValue, DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable newValue) {

}];
```

`

Comment: Thank you! As you can surely tell, I am unexperienced in Objective-C. Where would this code be put? Does the DJI SDK kit have a Main Loop or queue where code is put to be executed?

Comment: @brayvan Generally the place to put this would be inside of the main view controller's viewDidLoad.  Then on the view controller's viewDidDisappear make sure to call [[DJISDKManager keyManager] stopAllListeningOfListeners:self]

Comment: Great, I implemented those changes. I am encountering a new problem. See this updated post if you have any suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802931/data-values-logged-remain-unchanged-dji-uxsdkdemo/50804288#50804288

Comment: Is there a way to log these changes with a controlled interval timer through NSTimer instead of calling only when the value for the key changes? It would be more ideal if I could pull the data every 100 milliseconds for example.